# How do you automatically set focus on a form field using yui

Tags: interface, yui, yahoo

I currently have an issue  where I want text field to be automatically selected when the user visits my  webpage, I currently  do this  by  Javascript  but  would, ideally, like to use YUI. After searching the web, i found this command,

> YAHOO.util.Dom.get("first_element").focus();

and

> YAHOO.util.Dom.get("text1t").focus();

but have had very little  luck getting it to work, one  suggestion was  to use a setTimeout fnction, but this seems a rather ugly way of doing it.

If anyone has any  suggstions I would be very grateful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try using [onAvailable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Event.html#method_onAvailable)

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onAvailable("elementId", function(me) { me.focus(); }, YAHOO.util.Dom.get("elementId"));
```

You may need to use a later event, like onContentReady or even onDOMReady if that doesn't work.